# Actual Deletion of account at an institution in AggCat

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

I have couple of inquiries regarding the case when an account existing in AggCat is actually removed by the client at his/her institution.

Scenario: There are 4 accounts, A, B, C, D at institution I. The client had the account A removed at his/her institution. The 4 accounts had been discovered and added to AggCat before the A was actually removed at the institution.

1: If we call `updateInstitutionLogin` (no credentials change), then does `getCustomerAccounts` return only three accounts B, C, D without calling `deleteAccount` in AggCat?

2: It seems to me that `deleteAccount` method must be called if some account is actually removed at an institution to remove the account in AggCat. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

When an account is removed from an Institution we will return an error code on the specified account letting you know that it is closed or no longer present on the website.

If you perform a GetAccount, GetCustomerAccounts, GetLoginAccounts there is a field "aggrStatusCode" that will provide an error code for that account.  It will show 0 if the account is working fine otherwise it will reference a code on the [error code page](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/0700_error_codes).  The account will show a 106 or a 324 if the account cannot be found for changes such as it being removed or changed in some way such as changing account nickname, and/or account number.

If you wish for this account to not be returned from our system you will need to perform a deleteAccount request as we do not remove accounts automatically.